# Selenium Python Unable To Simulate Mouse Click

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, xpath

I would like to emulate clicking on a webpage menu item using Python/Selenium but I get the following error message:

```
ElementNotVisibleException: Cannot click on element
```

This is my code:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()

frame = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("frame[name='MenuFrame']")
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
driver.implicitly_wait(15)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@url,'History')]").click()
```

The webpage element is shown here:

[image]

I guess I need to somehow access the onclick event within the element but haven't been able to work out how to do that

Many thanks

Comment: Ok managed to solve this by simply using:

Comment: driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.menu1')[0].click()

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using correct version of driver compatible to your browser.

Answer (score 0):

I've found issues with clicking via Selenium before and got around it by using Javascript to click the element.

e.g.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)

my_xpath = "//frame[@name='MenuFrame']"
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//frame[@name='MenuFrame']]")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, my_xpath))) # wait until it's clickable
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button) # JS to click the element
```

Comment: It still says ElementNotVisibleException: Cannot click on element if I do the wait as posted above

Comment: Just to check, is the parent element an iFrame?

Comment: If it is an iFrame then you need to switch to that first using driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("ID-OF-PARENT-ELEMENT"))

Answer (score 0):

1. Pls try using find by id='divshowmenu'
2. Ensure the element is clickable before performing click:

   ```
   wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By locator));
   ```